# python if statement not working correctly with gensim language model

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

If statement not working properly when else added. The else statement prints when the if statement should.

Doesnt work:

```
variable = 'programming'

for i, word in enumerate(wv.vocab):
    if word == variable:
        print("Is ready to be measured")
    else:
        print("text to clean")
        #do this
        break
```

The below works showing the term variable is in the model wv.vocab

```
variable = 'programming'

for i, word in enumerate(wv.vocab):
    if word == variable:
        print("Is ready to be measured")
    #else:
        #print("text to clean")
        #do this
        break
```

When the variable is changed to something not in the model it does not work.

```
variable = 'programmings'

for i, word in enumerate(wv.vocab):
    if word == variable:
        print("Is ready to be measured")
    #else:
        #print("text to clean")
        #do this
        break
```

Comment: `break` stops the `for` loop iteration. Think about it for a second: is it actually in the right place in your first example?

Comment: @VisioN Ah thank you, weirdly I moved it back to the if statement line depth and none of them work, so maybe there is more to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VisionN thank you.

```
for i, word in enumerate(wv.vocab):
    if word == variable:
        print("Is ready to be measured")
        break
    else:
         print("text to clean")
```